# Entity framework - group by and count clause

Tags: entity-framework-5

I want to write an query with group by and count clause in Entity framework. like employees and managers and display all employees based on manager

any code samples

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var employeesByManager = db.Employees.
                            GroupBy(emp => emp.Manager.EmployeeName, emp => emp).
                            ToList();

var employeeCountsByManager = db.Employees.
                                 Select(emp => new { ManagerName = emp.EmployeeName, EmployeeCount = emp.Employees.Count() }).
                                 Where(a => a.EmployeeCount > 0).
                                 ToList();
```

You can, of course, get the employees grouped by manager in a similar manner as counts.  The `GroupBy` method is just a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I want to display EmployeeName and reporting persons for that Manager. its a single table - Employee which has a ManagerId which points back to employeeId. How to handle in single table

Comment: Updated to reflect this.  This assumes you have a 'belongs to' `Manager` relation mapped by `ManagerId` and a 'has many' `Employees` collection mapped similarly but in reverse.